# jQuery Uploadify Question

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, content-management-system, uploadify, business-catalyst

First off I am asking here vs the Uploadify forums because I am hoping to get a quicker answer to my issue. =>

I am using a CMS for my web site (Business Catalyst) and I do not have server side access. I cannot write to a folder etc. I would like to use Uploadify because of its features for the file upload in a form. I need to be able to have the upload file sent with the form. I am not sure if this is even possible but I am asking to see if it is.

A guy on the Uploadify forums said this: "You need a script like php, asp and so on for moving the file uploaded...But you can work this without php for your form file...
Example:

myform.html and on it using your upload form"

I am a bit confused as what exactly he is saying to do there.

Any advice about what to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with people both here and on other forums (and support for Business Catalyst) I have come to the conclusion that with Business Catalyst you cannot use Uploadify. Since you do not have server side access there is no way around setting up this to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

What the guy is trying to say is the following:

- You can write your page with an uploader (using uploadify or any
  uploader) normally
- But, for the file to be uploaded phisically, the server has to be
  configured to accept uploads from  your page
- Also, to be able to do something with your file in the server (for
  example, move it or save it to database), it has to be done with a
  server scripting language: (php, asp.net, ruby, etc)

So, you can build your page using uploadify but there's no guarantee that the file will be saved on the server.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, if I could get the file to be attached to the email I get that is all I need. I assume that this won't work since I do not have server side access.

Comment: Was just thinking about something. I can use the standard file upload field and accept files, the question is how would I go about configuring Uploadify to use the process. Make sense?

Comment: Been messing with this a little. Can the javascript be tweaked to send the file with the form and let the CMS handle it like it normally does with form file uploads? Here is a page I have been messing with: http://ubhape2remodel.businesscatalyst.com/test.html